# How can i iterate through all the files present in a directory and replace the match with text in all the files using regex in ant

Tags: java, xml, build, ant, devops

for example i had the following directory with the files as below:`D:\list\run

```
D:
  list
      run
      class.txt
      implement.txt
      test.txt`
```

under run folder i have all the .txt files. I need to iterate through all the files and using ant regex i need to match "java" word in all the files . if it contains the word it should be replace with python.

I tried it using for-each and regex nothing worked out:
Can anyone say how can i resolve this

Thanks!!!! `

Comment: Why do you need to do this in Ant specifically?

Comment: I had all my build scripts in ant build.xml file. that's the reason that i need to implement it in ant script